# Find $\frac {dy}{dx}$ when $x=t+\frac {1}{t}$ and $y=t-\frac {1}{t}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ when $x=t+\dfrac {1}{t}$ and $y=t-\dfrac {1}{t}$.

My attempt: we have that
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {dy}{dt}.\dfrac {dt}{dx}$$
but, what's $t$ to be replaced with?

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}/\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ could depend on $t$. There's nothing inherently wrong with that. In general, it may be that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ might take multiple values for a given value of $x$ or $y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Note that
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {dy}{dt}.\dfrac {dt}{dx}=\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)^{-1}=\frac{t+1/t}{t-1/t}=\frac{x}{y}.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$x^2 =\left(t+\dfrac {1}{t}\right)^2 =t^2 +\frac{1}{t^2} +2=\left(t-\dfrac {1}{t}\right)^2 +4 =y^2 +4$$

Hence,

$$2xdx = 2ydy \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y} =\frac{t^2+1}{t^2-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

You're right to use $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}\ .$$

The thing you're missing is $$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{dt/dx}\ ,$$

and this result is true for first derivates (but not higher ones in general).

Can you take it from here?